# populating a ListVIew with a Spinner , Help :/

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments, android-spinner

I'm currently stuck with my app right now. I'm developing a food tracker app that basically keep track of the food you consumed. Where it has a spinner filled with an array of items"food". I have buttons in my layout besides the first spinner below each  title of "breakfast, lunch, dinner" so if the user wants to add another food entry they would just Simply click on the button to add another spinner"food items".

The issue with this is that it over laps the textview of the lunch, dinner. Also, the user wont be able to delete the entry they had selected from the spinner.

My question is how would I implement it to where I just have one spinner for each breakfast,lunch, and dinner and a button to save the entry so that it could populate in a listview instead of add another Spinner. I hope I'm making sense. THis is what I have so far. THank you in advance.

[image]

main_content.xml

```
      <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:weightSum="1">


         <TextView
         android:id="@+id/textView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/title"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

       <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/BLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
            android:text="@string/breakfast"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/bkSpinner"
            android:layout_weight="0.21"
            android:entries="@array/allFoodItems" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addNewBItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/BButton"
            android:layout_column="13"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BLL"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addNewDItem"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/addNewDItem"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />


          </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addNewDItem"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
            android:text="Lunch"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/LSpinner"
            android:layout_weight="0.21"
            android:entries="@array/allFoodItems"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addNewLItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="@string/LButton"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />
           </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/DLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/LLL"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LLL"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addNewDItem">



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
            android:paddingBottom="130dp"
            android:text="@string/dinner"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LLL"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/LLL"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/dnSpinner"
            android:entries="@array/allFoodItems" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addNewDItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
            android:text="@string/DButton"
            android:layout_gravity="right" />

        </LinearLayout>


     <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.31">




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/totalCal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/calories"
    android:layout_width="94dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
       </RelativeLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: you can use database. When add item, you save it to database and show it to list view

Comment: when they click on a select item in the spinner for example

steak <item in the spinner> and they press on button"add entry"
wanted it to populate in the listview . 

thats how I wanted to set it up since the way I have it the spinners are over lapping

Comment: https://github.com/henrychuangtw/ReuseSpinner

Comment: How can I implement it to where when they select an item on the spinner and next to it there's a button that saves the selected item and then it displays it to a listview?